# create git alias for `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline`

Tags: git, repository

I use the command `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline` very often and I want to create an git alias for `--all --decorate --graph --oneline`.

I tried with `git config --global alias.adgo "--all --decorate --graph --oneline"`, but when I typed `git log adgo` afterward, an error message was displayed, saying `"fatal, ambiguous argument adgo"`.

Could someone tell how to get this git alias working? I have been struggling for a while now. Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can't alias just a set of parameters like that, you have to alias the *command*. Try `git config --global alias.adgo "log --all ..."`.

Comment: For what it's worth this alias is often spelled `lola`: http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html (`--oneline`, which was added to Git after this April 2010 blog entry, is short for `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to define it as

```
git config --global alias.adgo  “log --all --decorate --graph --oneline”
```

then use it as

```
git adgo
```

Comment: u must use `"` instead of `'` in window

Comment: ‘Should’, not ‘must’, but as you felt the need to comment on a 7yr old note, I updated it!

Comment: a 7yr old note but until yesterday, I copied pasted your answer which used `'` in my window machine, there was an error. I was so confused, then I replaced `'` with `"` and it was ok. I think it may be more cute if typing `git adog` than `git adgo`- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElVkf.jpg

Comment: @lamvuNguyen Just for completeness, both _should_ work, but  when copy & pasting from the web to a terminal, it's not unusual to find that somewhere along the way, something has replaced a 'straight' quote with a 'curly' quote, which causes an error in the shell - just a guess, though.  See https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html for background.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set like this:

```sh
git config --global alias.adgo "--all --decorate --graph --oneline"
```

Have to run this:

```sh
git config --global alias.adgo "log --all --decorate --graph --oneline"
```

Now try running this command

```sh
git adgo
```

The one who have taught you git didn't told you that this is the right way to set an alias:

```sh
git config --global alias.<alias> "<cmd> <options>"
```

HOPE THIS ANSWER HELPED!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your contribution, but in this case, I don't think you'd adding new information to the accepted answer, you're just explaining the same thing in more words. Adding a new answer to an old question is encouraged if you can provide a better answer or new information, but generally not just for rephrasing the same information.